# How to add index with page numbers using itextshap?

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, model-view-controller, itext

I’ve a requirement where I need to generate a **PDF** file with **Index along with Page numbers**. I'm using **ItextSharp** for generating PDF. The Document may contains hundreds of pages. The data in the PDF document will be the **dynamic data**.
Here is my Code to generate the PDF :

```
Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:/Sample1.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f))
using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
{
       PdfPageEventHelper pageEventHelper = new PdfPageEventHelper();
       writer.PageEvent = pageEventHelper;
       doc.SetMargins(20, 20, 50, 50);
       doc.NewPage();
       doc.Open();
       var Content = writer.DirectContent;
       var pageBorderRect = new Rectangle(doc.PageSize);
       ………..
       ………………..
       ………………..
       ………..
       doc.Close();
}
```

And to **add** the **page numbers** to generated document I used the following method

```
public void AddPageNumber(string BidNumber)
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Sample1.pdf");
            Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            Font boldfont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 14, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
                {
                    int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                   for (int j = 2; j <= pages; j++)
                    {
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetUnderContent(j), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase((j - 1).ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
                    }
                }
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\newPDF.pdf", bytes);
        }
```

Now, I need to create and add the **Index with page numbers** for this document. Here my problem is the index content also is dynamic data which will be some data in the document.
While searching for my requirement, I found this,

```
int chapTemplateCounter = 0;
    public override void OnChapter(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition, Paragraph title)
    {
        base.OnChapter(writer, document, paragraphPosition, title);

        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);

        tableOfContentsTemplateList[chapTemplateCounter].BeginText();
        tableOfContentsTemplateList[chapTemplateCounter].SetFontAndSize(bfTimes, 12);
        tableOfContentsTemplateList[chapTemplateCounter].SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
        tableOfContentsTemplateList[chapTemplateCounter].ShowText("" + writer.PageNumber);
        tableOfContentsTemplateList[chapTemplateCounter].EndText();

        chapTemplateCounter++;
    }
```

I think it is useful for the static headers. How can I add index with page numbers in document with this code or Is it the correct way to generate PDF using **Itextsharp**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: might this link helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344060/generate-table-of-content-using-itextsharp

Comment: Use can check this link, might be help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515548/how-to-add-page-number-in-footer-in-pdf-by-itextsharp

Comment: How exactly are the words to put into the index to be chosen? Shall there be an external list of words and you merely look for the occurrences of those words? Or shall the words to index somehow automatically be determined?

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems that you want to create a table of contents. I linked to a duplicate question in case you want to meet your requirement using iText 5. I would recommend you to upgrade to iText 7 though, and to take a look at the TOC examples in this chapter. http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-6-creating-actions-destinations-and-bookmarks

Comment: @mkl : actually, the words are in index page coming from the Database which will be given by the users, We can't expect any thing.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie If I read Saikiran's comments correctly, he really tries to create an index, not a toc.

Comment: OK, I reopened the question. There's a class `IndexEvents` in iText 5 for this kind of work. I'm pretty sure I have an example somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [IndexWords](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events-itext5/page-events-chunks#2888-indexwords.java) example.

In this example, we create an instance of the `IndexEvents` class, and we use that instance as a page event:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
IndexEvents index = new IndexEvents();
writer.setPageEvent(index);
```

Now when we add content to the document, we marks the words that we want to index like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Quick brown fox ");
p.add(index.create("jumps", "Jump"));
p.add(" over the lazy dog.");
document.add(p);
```

In this paragraph, we have marked the word "jumps" so that it is listed in the index as "Jump".

Or we mark words like this:

```
p = new Paragraph();
p.add(index.create("Quick brown fox", "Fox", "quick, brown"));
p.add(new Chunk(" jumps over "));
p.add(index.create("the lazy dog.", "Dog", "lazy"));
p.add(index.create(" ", "Jumping"));
document.add(p);
```

In this case, we have marked "Quick brown fox" with the keyword "Fox" and we have added a specification: "quick, brown". We have also added a keyword "Dog" and the specification "lazy". Finally, we also added a key word "Jumping".

Or we mark words like this:

```
p = new Paragraph();
p.add(new Chunk("The fox is "));
p.add(index.create("brown", "Color", "brown"));
p.add(index.create(" ", "Brown", "color", "see Color; brown"));
p.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
document.add(p);
```

We mark "brown" as a "Color" and we specify "brown". We also add a reference. When people search or index for the word "Brown", we'll refer to "Color".

Once we have added all the content we need, we go to a new page, and we create the index:

```
document.newPage();
// we add the index
document.add(new Paragraph("Index:"));
List<Entry> list = index.getSortedEntries();
for (Entry entry : list) {
    Paragraph in = new Paragraph();
    in.add(new Chunk(entry.getIn1()));
    if (entry.getIn2().length() > 0) {
        in.add(new Chunk("; " + entry.getIn2()));
    }
    if (entry.getIn3().length() > 0) {
        in.add(new Chunk(" (" + entry.getIn3() + ")"));
    }
    List<Integer> pages = entry.getPagenumbers();
    List<String> tags = entry.getTags();
    in.add(": ");
    for (int i = 0, x = pages.size(); i < x; i++) {
        Chunk pagenr = new Chunk(" p" + pages.get(i));
        pagenr.setLocalGoto((String) tags.get(i));
        in.add(pagenr);
    }
    document.add(in);
}
```

You can check the result here: [index_words.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/events/cmp_index_words.pdf)

[image]